# How to do Progressive Image?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, optimization, layer

My website loading image like,

[image]

How can i change to,

[image]

Anyone help me, Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Magento. Please try a StackExchange website like [graphicdesign.se], [webmasters.se] or just try on [so]

Comment: @7ochem https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110797/122839